# Querying objectId of a pointer class in Parse.com - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to retrieve the objectId as a string from my User class in Parse, but I'm getting a NullPointer.

```
Log.w(getClass().toString(), ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getParseObject("currentGroup").getObjectId());

java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

I'm querying the column "currentGroup", which is a pointer to a class called "Group". All I want is to retrieve its objectId. Both the currentGroup and Group objectId columns have data. They are not null. What's going on here?

**Error:**

It seems to think the object is null but I can't see why it would be.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
  'java.lang.String com.parse.ParseObject.getObjectId()' on a null object reference
at at com.yitter.android.fragment.FeedFragment.retrieveData(FeedFragment.java:112)
at com.yitter.android.fragment.FeedFragment.onCreateView(FeedFragment.java:105)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1638)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1085)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: please add the message error so we will be able to understand which call of this chain produce the Null exception

Comment: Okay I included the error.

Comment: Are you sure that "currentGroup" is in your User class? If it does, check for spelling problem. Did you have any kind of LogIn?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I found a solution, shown below, but I'm not sure why getting the objectId of a pointer column directly from ParseUser.getCurrentUser() is not possible when the method seems to be provided...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Orders");
        ParseObject obj = ParseObject.createWithoutData("ShopLocations",idd); // this pointer object class name and pointer value
        query.whereEqualTo("shop", obj); // this pointer object and parse object
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {}}
```

*This is working correctly retrieving data from parse.*

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You can not retrieve the object of a pointer using ParseUser.getCurrentUser(). You have to do a full ParseUser query to retrieve the current User, by finding the user in your User table with an objectId equal to ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId().

```
 ParseQuery query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> users, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) for (userObject : users) {
                    // I retrieve the objectId from the pointer
                    // only after directly querying for the current User.
                    userObject.getParseObject("currentGroup").getObjectId(); 
                }
            }
        });
```

At least, this is the only way I managed to get this to work in my app. I'm not sure why the `.getParseObject()` method is available to `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` if you can't just directly retrieve the objectId of the specified pointer object, but oh well. If anyone knows, I'd love to know how you did it.